# django .objects.values_list how to exlude None value

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I'm using django .objects.values_list to get all the values of a filed of Model:

```
 def gen_choice(filed):
        return list(Mymodel.objects.values_list(filed, flat=True).distinct())
```

I want to exclude all the None value in the above query set :

```
Mymodel.objects.values_list(filed, flat=True).distinct()
```

Or the list:

```
list(Mymodel.objects.values_list(filed, flat=True).distinct())
```

I have tried:

```
 def gen_choice(filed):
        return list(Mymodel.objects.exclude(filed=None).values_list(filed, flat=True).distinct())
```

Error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'filed' into field. Choices are:
```

Comment: put filed in quotes within values_list. So `.values_list("filed", flat=True)`

Comment: the filed is a argument ,not a real name of the filed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass this as kwargs, so:

```
def gen_choice(flield):
    return list(
        Mymodel.objects.exclude(**{field: None})
        .values_list(field, flat=True)
        .distinct()
    )
```

Comment: it works thanks,what dose '**' mean ?

Comment: @William: you "unpack" a dictionary as keyword parameters, so `f(**{'a': 4})` is equivalent to `f(a=4)`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Hi friend can you help me with this question too,this one is really very hard https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74496585/django-filter-pagination-only-the-first-search-filed-failed